# CGLib not coping property values

Tags: java, spring, cglib

I have controller wired with @Value annotation on its properties, but something strange happens:

```
08:20:31.400 [main] ERROR Controller - postConstruct(): days: 14
08:20:31.401 [main] ERROR Controller - postConstruct(): pattern: dd-MM-yyyy
08:20:32.812 [main] ERROR Controller$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$15b7ad5 - initBindeR(): propertyConf null
08:20:32.812 [main] ERROR Controller$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$15b7ad5 - initBindeR(): pattern: null
```

As you can see, postConstruct method sees those properties, but when class is instrumentilized by cglib values are gone. Anyone knows what happend? I have no idea. Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

CGLib creates a proxy to Controller ($$15b7ad5), that proxy isn't aware of the @value as it's not understood by the CGLib library.

Comment: Any way to overcome this? :<

Comment: To see those properties in the controller? :)

Comment: sure you want to read values from there :) but for which purpose ? why you've to proxy a Spring controller ?

Comment: I have Spring Security annotations on it. :)